# Visual Studio 2013 Crashing when clicking "Attach to Process"

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Whenever I click "Attach to Process..." in the Visual Studio 2013 Visual studio crashes on me before seeing the attach dialog, regardless of if I have a project loaded or not. I can click debug and get into debug mode but I really need to attach.

Things I've Tried:

- Uninstalled and Reinstalled VS
- Loading Visual Studio with "/safemode"
- Loading Visual Studio with "/log" and checking the log (no notable errors listed)
- Deleting my Local Temp folder

Additional Info:

- OS: Windows 8
- Version: Visual Studio 2013 Update 4
- Exeption when debugging VS crash:
  An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommonIDE.dll

Not sure what else to try or where else to look, I have VS 2015 preview install and it has no problems.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In my case the culprit was "PowerShell tools for Visual Studio 2013". I disabled it and the problem disappeared.

<kbd>Tools</kbd> => <kbd>Extensions and Updates...</kbd> => choose the extension and press <kbd>Disable</kbd>

Comment: This solution solved it for me too. Also, when that plugin is enabled, the "Attach to process" list is always empty.

Comment: I had a similar issue with the latest version of the PS tools plugin and Visual Studio 2015. It didn't crash but the Attach to Process dialog took 30-60 seconds to pop up while Visual Studio was actively giving the focus other open applications.

Comment: How to deactivate PowerShell Tools??

Comment: Menu "Tools" => "Extensions and Updates.." => choose the extension and press 'Disable' button

Comment: I received this error after updating VS2015 with Update 1. Following the above instructions worked and I can now attach to processes without issue.

Comment: In VS 2015  I cant even attach to process without powershell tools installed.  It prompts me for a download.

Comment: Installed the only option is to uninstall not disable.

Comment: This happened to me in Visual Studio 2017. "Download PowerShell v3 Tools" message box appears and Visual Studio freezes with empty Attach to Process window and stops working. Disabling PowerShell tools helped me. Thank you! It is unimaginably how Microsoft cannot fix such problems after several years and multiple generations of Visual Studio IDE.